# サブドメインではなく、サブディレクトリでアプリを分けたい

Tags: cakephp, apache, laravel

Apache 2.4で
`/var/www/html/laravel` （Laravel 5.1が入っています
`/var/www/html/cakephp` （CakePHP 3.2が入っています

このように配置した時に、

```
http://example.com/laravel
http://example.com/cakephp
```

のようにアクセスさせたいと思いますが、可能でしょうか？

http://example.com/laravel/public/
の様に後ろにセグメントが付く形であれば問題ありません。

Answer (score 1):

可能です。

ただし、DocumentRoot直下にアプリケーションを設置すると公開すべきではないファイルにアクセスされる可能性があるため、アプリケーションは別のところに設置して、それぞれの公開ディレクトリ(public, webroot)をシンボリックリンクでDocumentRootに持ってくる方法をお勧めします。

```
/var/www/laravel
/var/www/cakephp
```

にアプリケーション本体を設置したとして

```
ln -s /var/www/laravel/public /var/www/html/laravel
ln -s /var/www/cakephp/webroot /var/www/html/cakephp
```

で、シンボリックリンクを作成します。